# How refer to a particular instance of twebbrowser? - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

If I create n Tabsheets at runtime and create one Webbrowser inside each tabsheet using a method such as:

```
        procedure createTab;
        var crm: TWebbrowser;
        var  ts: TsTabSheet;
        begin
        
       //Instance of tabsheet
       ts             :=  TsTabSheet.Create(pageControl);
       ts.PageControl :=  pageControl;
        
       //Instance of webbrowser          
       crm                   :=  TWebbrowser.Create(ts);
       crm.Parent            :=  TWinControl(ts);
       crm.Align             :=  alClient;
       end;
```

When one of tabsheet instance is active how could I know which webbrowser is inside it? Sample:

```
  procedure navigateToActiveTabsheet(url: string);
          begin
           //TO DO - How navigate to webbrowser inside active tabsheet?
          end;
```

Comment: You should not be casting if at all possible. So don't write crm.Parent            :=  TWinControl(ts); because that will make your code compile no matter what ts really is. Just remove the cast. In cases where a cast is needed use the as operator and so have runtime checking of the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controls property of a windowed control allows you to obtain every child control. Because these children can be any TControl descendent, you'll need to cast to TWebBrowser. Use the as operator to benefit from runtime validity checking of the cast:

```
procedure navigateToActiveTabsheet(url: string); 
var
  wb: TWebBrowser;
begin    
  wb := pageControl.ActivePage.Controls[0] as TWebBrowser;
  wb.Navigate(url);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  WB: TWebBrowser;

WB := TWebBrowser(pageControl.ActivePage.Controls[0]);
```